# Compiler Support for Enum Values

Tags: c++, enums, compilation, standards

Given an `enum` declared like so:

```
enum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
};
```

What is the general compiler support with reference to § 7.2 of the C++11 standard? Specifically, this excerpt from § 7.2.2:

> If the first enumerator has no initializer, the value of the
>   corresponding constant is zero. An enumerator-definition without an
>   initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the
>   value of the previous enumerator by one.

**Can I expect the common, modern compilers (GCC, Intel, Clang, recent versions of CL, *others*), to give the same results, that is, `A = 0`, `B = 1`, `C = 2`, and `D = 3`?**

Comment: I'd go a bit farther than James. If a compiler doesn't implement this correctly, *shoot it*. Worrying about this is like worrying about whether your compiler implements `switch` correctly.

Comment: @NicolBolas Cool, that's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule you cite is not new in C++11. It's part of C++03, C++98, C11, C99, and C89. This rule existed *before* these languages were ever standardized. Java and C# both inherited this behavior with their enums.

Yes, compilers support this part of the langauge. Just like they support `if`, `switch`, `#define`, `int`s and other *basic language constructs*.

We're not talking about r-value references or lambdas or something. This is core stuff from before many programmers today *were even born*.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's always good to check. It wouldn't be the first time I was surprised by some weird non-compliant quirk of an otherwise perfectly good compiler.

Comment: I did find a bug in K&R's original compiler in roughly this area, but only when you tried to use these values in expressions before the final `}`. But that was in their pre-1989 compiler so I couldn't really argue that it violated the standard.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if compiler supports standard.

```
enum { a, b, c=0 };
enum { d, e, f=e+2 };
```

defines `a`, `c`, and `d` to be zero, `b` and `e` to be 1, and `f` to be 3.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the question. Do these compilers support *this* part of the standard?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That code is from the C++ standard document. It's full of interesting examples.